# How to execute a MongoDB query in the native node-mongo-native driver?

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native, mongo-c-driver

is there any way I can pass a MongoDB query like `db.things.find()` directly to the *Mongo C Driver* or the Javascript driver *node-mongo-native* to make a query?

I am wondering the native driver is able to evaluate the query and return the result.

How to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's basically the whole point of a Mongo driver. :)

Comment: I am still not sure what you are searching for. From where do you want to make the query to the driver?

Comment: @nutlike I want to pass the javascript query in to the driver without creating the Bson query object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method mongo_simple_str_command(…) in [*mongo.h*](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html) seems to be what you are searching for.

```
mongo_simple_str_command(conn, db, "$eval", "db.foo.find()", out);
```

I found an usage example here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/test/platform/linux/timeouts.c

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see *mongo_run_command* in the mongo.h, I will try it later today.

Comment: @sza: Would you mind sharing the results of your try? Since I never used this I am curious if it worked out.

Comment: Technically this works but the find() actually returns a iterator, to make it fully work, i have to append a javascript function something like .forEach(function(x){printjson(x);}).