# How to execute a mongo query string on a node server using native node driver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to pass a string like "db.users.find()" to the node server and have it execute the command. This question: [How to execute a MongoDB query in the native node-mongo-native driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028907/how-to-execute-a-mongodb-query-in-the-native-node-mongo-native-driver) has an answer for the C- driver.

Is there a way to do it directly with the native node driver?
I've tried doing

```
db.eval('function(){'+query+'}', function(err, result){
  console.log("the result is", result
});
```

and it doesn't work. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, but the function you create needs to return something usable to the callback.  For example:

```
var query = 'db.users.find()';
db.eval('function(){ return ' + query + '.toArray(); }', function(err, result){
  console.log("the result is", result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! also it looks like i need a role that allows anyAction on anyResource to be able to run this. Struggling with that. Do you know how to do that? Can't find a good example :(

Comment: Sorry, never looked into that; probably best to post that as a separate question if you're stuck.

Comment: This is a great answer but eval is deprecated since version MongoDB 3.0, and they will remove it, I don't know what can be the alternative

Comment: Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499375/mongodb-3-db-eval-alternative

Comment: `.eval` is deprecated from v4.2